# Edge detection for multiple images

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, edge-detection

Hi I have a set of images and I want to do edge detection for all the images at once. I can do it manually for each image but I believe that is not the right way to do so. How can I do it for all the images at once? I think it should be in a loop but I don't know how to implement that

I have read multiple images as grayscale and now I want to do edge detection for all the images. How do we select the maximum and minimum value parameters for the Canny function. The images can be accessed [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Cl0RPsO3LooQ4pJSTToRO_oqSUAKZNg_)

```
import glob
import cv2

images = [cv2.imread(file,0) for file in glob.glob("images/*.jpg")]
edges = cv2.Canny(images,100,200)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To automatically select the maximum and minimum values for `cv2.Canny()` you can use the `auto_canny()` function created by Adrian Rosebrock in his blog *[Zero-parameter, automatic Canny edge detection with Python and OpenCV](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/04/06/zero-parameter-automatic-canny-edge-detection-with-python-and-opencv/)*. The idea is to compute the median of the pixel intensities in the image then take this median value to determine the `lower` and `upper` thresholds. For a more detailed explanation, check out his blog. Here's the function

```
def auto_canny(image, sigma=0.33):
    # Compute the median of the single channel pixel intensities
    v = np.median(image)

    # Apply automatic Canny edge detection using the computed median
    lower = int(max(0, (1.0 - sigma) * v))
    upper = int(min(255, (1.0 + sigma) * v))
    return cv2.Canny(image, lower, upper)
```

---

To perform edge detection on multiple images, you can use the `glob` library to iterate through each image, apply canny edge detection, then save the image. Here's the results

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import glob

def auto_canny(image, sigma=0.33):
    # Compute the median of the single channel pixel intensities
    v = np.median(image)

    # Apply automatic Canny edge detection using the computed median
    lower = int(max(0, (1.0 - sigma) * v))
    upper = int(min(255, (1.0 + sigma) * v))
    return cv2.Canny(image, lower, upper)

# Read in each image and convert to grayscale
images = [cv2.imread(file,0) for file in glob.glob("images/*.jpg")]

# Iterate through each image, perform edge detection, and save image
number = 0
for image in images:
    canny = auto_canny(image)
    cv2.imwrite('canny_{}.png'.format(number), canny)
    number += 1
```